# Why I can't search through this site with keywords by tagged questions?

Tags: support, tags, search

If we search something through stackoverflow.com we pass keywords into query string like this: `/search?q=garden` and gets appropriate results.

Also we can find tagged questions with URL like this: `/questions/tagged/iis`

But I can't find tagged questions with specified keywords! Something like this: `/questions/tagged/iis/search?q=garden`

In REST we trust :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specify tags in the search query, e.g. `[iis]`.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iis]+garden

[Search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) provide more information (link is on the right side of search results).

Comment: That sounded strange IMO, but is correct in the site's search box and in stackoverflow.com/search you can filter by tag by putting the name of the tage between square brackets like [php]

Comment: @Trufa It will also auto-taggify common tags like php, so searching for "garden php" is the same as searching for "garden [php]". (iis isn't common enough for that though)

Comment: nice did not know that!