# Why doesn't Stack Overflow search return questions and answers with tags that match the search keywords?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

There must already be an answer somewhere, but I have been searching and searching and haven't found it, so:

If I search on Stack Overflow for `ssas Query timeout expired HYT00` I get no results, but if I search for `[ssas] Query timeout expired HYT00` I get two results. This seems like a less-than-ideal user experience, as it requires that users a) be aware of tags, b) remember to search with them and c) guess which of their search keywords might exist as tags. (I know, I know, tags are second nature to you all, but they're not to me and I expect many others.)

Am I right in thinking that the search engine doesn't check for tags matching the search terms, and if so wouldn't doing this be a better experience?

Edit:

Ah, based on a comment to the answer to [Why I can't search through this site with keywords by tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77402/why-i-cant-search-through-this-site-with-keywords-by-tagged-questions), this promotion *is* done for some tags, presumably the most popular. So I guess my question should be why isn't it done for more or all tags?

Comment: because `[ssas]` is searching for the tag. without the `[]` your then searching for the text ssas in the question and answers. when you do a search click *"Advanced Search Tips"* and at the bottom you have *"For more details on advanced search [visit our help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)"*

Comment: @Memor-X Yes, I understand how tags work, and I've read the search tips and help pages and I didn't find an answer to my question there. I'm asking why the search engine doesn't treat keywords as tags if tags with the same name exist. Using the example queries I gave, if I forget to make `ssas` a tag the results tell me there are no relevant questions, but there are at least two very relevant questions. Why doesn't the search engine "promote" the `ssas` keyword to a tag and then give me the relevant questions?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is going to have to do with overhead. Search results are generally cached, and the popularity of a tag may have something to do with the reduced ability to search it.

Comment: Ah! This *has* been more or less asked and answered before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags, although that question assumes knowledge that keyword-to-tag conversion happens in at least some instances.

Comment: See also: [Why does searching for SSAS which has it's own set of tags, return lots of 'SSA' results first?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272429/3614835).  Inferring the tag here would work around the stemmer guessing incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, interesting. That example seems like a good argument for expanding the set of keywords that are automatically promoted to tags.